# Node and async: Why is await not being honored in a sub-function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I'm a Node.js student, and I'm writing a brief example.  The get on /org works as expected.

With the get on /orgg I tried to segregate the server "fetch the data" logic from the controller.  However, the getRowsAsync() immediately returns a Promise.

This "put the await in express.get()" isn't good for hiding logic.  If my biz logic needed some sequential Promises then the biz logic would have to bubble into the controller.

How can I do the equivalent to calling "doBizLogic()" in the controller, hiding my awaits, and having the controller wait for the logic to complete?  *Must* I pass a callback function to the biz logic to make this scheme work?

Here is my index.js.  I omit database.js, but I borrowed it from https://mhagemann.medium.com/create-a-mysql-database-middleware-with-node-js-8-and-async-await-6984a09d49f4

```
const express = require("express");
const urlPort = 3000;
let app = express();
let mysql = require("mysql2");
let pool = require("./database");

app.listen(urlPort, () => {
  console.log("Server is running at port " + urlPort);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("This app responds to /org and /org/:id only.");
});

app.get("/org", async (req, res) => {
  let rows = await getRows("select * from org");
  // the log always prints a JSON array.
  console.log("in app.get for /org, rows: ", rows);
  res.send(rows);
});

app.get("/orgg", (req, res) => {
  let rows = getRowsAsync();
  // the log() prints immediately prints a Promise.
  console.log("in app.get for /orgg, rows: ", rows);
  res.send(rows);
});

function getRows(sql, params = []) {
  let rows = pool.query(sql, params);
  // the log() prints a Promise.
  console.log("in getRows, rows: ", rows); // returns 
  return rows;
}

async function getRowsAsync() {
  let rows = await getRows("select * from org");
  // the log() prints a JSON array, once it is finally called.
  console.log("in getRowsAsync, rows: ", rows);
  return rows;
}
```

Comment: You need `let rows = await getRowsAsync()`

Comment: Whether your function is syncrhonous or asynchronous is not "business logic" that you should hide. It's just part of a function's definition, no different from its arguments or return value. The caller needs to know whether the function is asynchronous, just like it needs to know how many arguments to pass.

Comment: OK, I can live with *this* solution.  I mark the " fcn" as app.get("/orgg, async fcn), with an await on getRowsAsync().  I then can bury any number of async/await combos as deep as I wish, such as in getRowsAsync1, calling ... getRowsAsyncN, which finally does DB work.  Any better solutions?

Answer (score 4):

**Your specific questions**

> How can I do the equivalent to calling "doBizLogic()" in the controller, hiding my awaits, and having the controller wait for the logic to complete?

You can't hide that logic.  Any API that "might" be asynchronous must be designed as an asynchronous API and the caller needs to know how to use the asynchronous API properly.

You cannot hide asynchronous-ness because there's no way in Javascript to make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.  If any part of your operation is asynchronous, then it will need an asynchronous interface to communicate the result and completion (via a promise, a callback or an event).

> Must I pass a callback function to the biz logic to make this scheme work?

You could use a callback, but I would suggest just returning a promise that the caller can use `await` on as that's a more modern design than a callback and is somewhat easier to program with, particularly if there are other asynchronous operations in the same function.  The caller will have to make use of that returned promise for things to work properly.

So, just have your caller use `await`.  The caller has to "know" it's an asynchronous interface anyway because you program with asynchronous interfaces differently than synchronous interfaces.

> This "put the await in express.get()" isn't good for hiding logic. If my biz logic needed some sequential Promises then the biz logic would have to bubble into the controller.

Yes, that's the way it is in Javascript.  A caller has to know if they are calling a synchronous or asynchronous API so they know how to get the result/err and completion.  There is no way around that unless you design all interfaces as asynchronous and treat all calls to those APIs as asynchronous (which is not efficient for entirely synchronous APIs).

> Why is await not being honored in a sub-function?

In this piece of code:

```
function getRows(sql, params = []) {
  let rows = pool.query(sql, params);
  // the log() prints a Promise.
  console.log("in getRows, rows: ", rows); // returns 
  return rows;
}
```

The code is not properly handling the asynchronous `pool.query()`.  That function apparently returns a promise and you aren't waiting for that promise to resolve either with `await` or `.then()`.  Therefore, when you try to log the value, you just get the promise.  This function will be returning the promise so a caller can get the value by using `.then()` or `await` on that promise.

**Await requires proper promise implementation**

I will also mention that in order for `await` to work properly for your callers, your function must return a promise that resolves or rejects when the asynchronous operation is complete and any resolved value or rejected error is in that promise also.  So, just slapping an `await` on a function that isn't returning a promise that is properly wired into the asynchronous operations will not work.  The promise must be correctly implemented for `await` to do its job.

**Use a promise-supporting version of mysql**

Since it appears you're using mysql, I'd strong suggest you get the module that implements a promise interface for the database so you can do all your asynchronous coding with promises, not plain callbacks.

The [link](https://mhagemann.medium.com/create-a-mysql-database-middleware-with-node-js-8-and-async-await-6984a09d49f4) you had in your question to a 2018 article shows lots of mysql examples using plain callbacks.  I would not recommend starting a new project using plain callbacks for asynchronous operations.  You will quickly learn to appreciate the advantages of using promise-based interfaces once you start doing that and promises are the modern way of handling asynchronous operations in Javascript.

**You must catch all promise rejections**

P.S. Any promise you use MUST have a `.catch()`  or an `await` with a `try/catch` somewhere in the call chain that will catch a potential rejected promise.  So, all your express request handlers that are calling your asynchronous APIs are missing that proper error handling.  Without that, you will get an uncaught promise rejection.  At best, the request handler will just never send a response.  At worst, your server will shut-down.  All possible rejected promises must be caught somewhere in your code.

So, something like this:

```
app.get("/org", async (req, res) => {
  let rows = await getRows("select * from org");
  // the log always prints a JSON array.
  console.log("in app.get for /org, rows: ", rows);
  res.send(rows);
});
```

should be something like this:

```
app.get("/org", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let rows = await getRows("select * from org");
    // the log always prints a JSON array.
    console.log("in app.get for /org, rows: ", rows);
    res.send(rows);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

Or, if you want to handle all errors centrally:

```
app.get("/org", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let rows = await getRows("select * from org");
    // the log always prints a JSON array.
    console.log("in app.get for /org, rows: ", rows);
    res.send(rows);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    next(e);          // forward to central Express error handler
  }
});
```

---

If you want to catch the error in your business logic so you can do something with it, but still eventually return an error back to your controller functions, then you can `catch` and `rethrow`:

```
async function getRows(params) {
  try {
      let rows = await pool.query("select * from org", params);
      console.log("in getRows, rows: ", rows);
      return rows;
  } catch(e) {
      // catch the error, log it and do whatever else you want with it
      // either return a value or rethrow some error
      //    usually, you would throw some error here
      //    so a failed operation rejects the promise
      //    this function returns
      console.log(e);
      // you can throw a different error if you want to invent
      // your own specific errors, rather than pass back db errors
      throw e;
  }      
}
```

Comment: jfriend00, these comments are too short for proper discussion of your helpful advice (thank you!)  But just a few notes.  I *do* use the promise-supporting "mysql2".  My sample getRows() is simplified for samples -- I can use your model for error handling.  Note that much biz logic must resolve "async" responses (and handle errors on-the-spot), before returning to app.get. For example, fetch data from two URLs and merge it, then return thru app.get.  So I seek "best practices" for resolving my promises in places deeper than in app.get.  Perhaps I have one method in my (above) comment.

Comment: @jerome - Then, `catch` locally in the business logic and rethrow from the catch whatever error you want the caller to see.  No need to rewrap in another promise to do that.  The business logic needs to reject when there's an error so you can't fully "handle" errors in the business logic.  Callers of business logic must know when there's an error and rejections are the mechanism of choice for errors when using promises.  The point is you just return the same promise chain and your business logic controls the resolved value or the rejected reason.  No need to wrap in another promise.

Comment: @Jerome - I added an example of catching the error at a local level, doing something, the rethrowing so the promise stays rejected and is communicated back to the caller as a rejection.